# Best Practise for SQL Replication / Load Managing

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, load, database-performance

I'm currently running an Ubuntu Server with Mariadb on it. It serves all sql requests for a Website (with a good amount of requests on it).

Few times a day we import large CSV files into the Database to update our Data. The Problem is, since those csv blast the db (import takes around 15 Minutes).

It seems to be using only 1 Core from 4 but still, the website (or better its sql requests during that time) get ridiculously slow. Now the question for me is what can I do here to affect the Website less to none?
I was considering Database replication to a different server, but I'm expecting that to use the same amount of ressources during the import time so no real benefit here I guess?

The other thing I considered is to have 2 SQL Databases, and during an import all requests should be switched to the other Database Server and I would basicly do each import twice, one on Server 1 (during that time Server 2 should serve the site) once thats done, the website has to be swiched to Server 1 and the import is done on Server 2. While that would work, it seems to be quite an effort for a non perfect solution (like how are requests handled during the switch from Server 1 to 2 and so on.

So what solutions exist here, preferably somewhat affordable.
All ideas and hints are welcome.

Thanks in advance
Best Regards

Menax

Comment: Regarding the 1 Thread issue, that seems to be fixable via the solution here, definately going to give it a try. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core

Comment: "SQL Server" is the name of a competing product.  Please do not use it when referring to MariaDB; it is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Is the import *replacing* an entire table?  If so, load it into a separate table, then swap it into place.  Essentially zero downtime, namely during the `RENAME TABLE`.  For details, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig or possibly http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

If the import is doing something else, please provide details.

One connection uses one core, no more.

**More** (from Comments)

```
SELECT  id, marchants_id
    from  products
    WHERE  links LIKE '%https://´www.merchant.com/productsite_5'
    limit  1
```

That is hard to optimize because of the *leading* wildcard in the `LIKE`.  Is that really what you need?  As it stands, that query must scan the table.

```
SELECT  id, price
    from  price_history
    WHERE  product_id = 5
    order by  id desc
    limit  1
```

That would benefit from `INDEX(product_id, id, price)` -- in that order.  With that index, the query will be as close to instantaneous as possible.

Please provide the rest of the transaction with the Update and Insert, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There is quite possibly a way to "batch" the actions rather than doing one product price at a time.  This *may* speed it up 10-fold.

Flip-flopping between two servers -- only if the data is readonly.  If you are otherwise modifying the tables, that would be a big nightmare.

For completely replacing a table,....

1. CREATE a new TABLE
2. Populate it
3. RENAME TABLE to swap the new table into place.

(But I still don't understand your processing well enough to say if this is best.  When you say "switch the live database", are you referring to a server (computer), a DATABASE (schema), or just one TABLE?

Comment: The Site basicly is kinda a price comparison site (not 100%, but I guess thats the closest thing to it without much explaining) In the Database there is a Table with Prices and its Product ID & Vendor ID + Date. Old prices are kept for pricehistory in a different table and whenever we get an updated csv file from any suppliers with new prices we import it. With multiple suppliers, most of them have between 30'000 and 50'000 products (per csv). And as there are different merchants not the entire table gets exchanged (updated) only parts of it.

Comment: @Menaxerius - How do you know which rows are being replaced?  (My suggestions are still valid, but the "partial" replacement adds some complexity.)  And, do all the updates come in at the same time?  Or do you replace data from one vendor at a time?

Comment: yes, that is known (its basicly all rows from that vendor with the vendor ID), they are replaced from one vendor at a time. So If I understand it correctly you suggest me to import them in a different table and then move all entrys from said vendor in the table where they are actualy used by the site?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: PS: What probably would work is to copy the table first to a different table, do the import there and then rename the table, but as of right now I don't know yet if the copying part would be less load

Comment: @Menaxerius - Does that 'replacement' involve deleting some rows (eg, merchandise not being sold anymore), inserting some rows (new merchandise), _and_ updating some rows (price changes, etc)?  Or... are there no new rows?  or no removed rows?

Comment: @Menaxerius - Also, do you "need" to keep the data "live" while doing the update?  (I ask all these things because "one size does _not_ fit all" when it comes to tricky tasks like this.)

Comment: I've split now everything to multiple imports, price imports that are more "urgent" that that take now around 3-4 Minutes per Merchant that basicly does this querys:
`364 Query SELECT id, marchants_id from products  WHERE links LIKE '%https://´www.merchant.com/productsite_5' limit 1
364 Query SELECT id, price from price_history  WHERE product_id = 5 order by id desc limit 1`
Followed by an update in the price table and insert in the (price history table whatever the old price was) if the data from db is different then the data in the csv.

Comment: the operation of the website shouldn't stop, what I considered is having a second sql server send all requests to that one during the import, and move it back once the import is done. So during the "update" it would display the "old" Data that are beeing switched to the new one, but then again, I'm expecting a similar load during the "sync" of the database, unless it has a good wait of noticing what data actualy changed. What I have zero experience with at this point. I'm willing to put some hours into research of that if thats the right direction.

Comment: Also would have to figure out if it would be better to switch the live database to the "second" Database and let the "main" db sync as master to the second (slave) or do it the other way around. I'm guessing I can select the tables that should be synced to exclude some like user tables in case I use the second as master.

Comment: The more I think about it, if I can do the import on a different db, and only the actual update / insert's are done on the live db either by master to master replication of the selected tables or write the import script to write the db to a different table would likely be a somewhat decent solution. So the question then is, is the replication process from mariadb (or any other db) "smart" enough to only sync the updates / inserts. In that case a master <-> master replication likely would be fine. If not it will cause conflicts as the data might be slightly different on both db's during import.

Comment: I need a clearer picture of whether the "import" adds rows, changes rows, and/or deletes rows from the main table.  Or it is practical to simply replace the table.  Each can be optimized in a different way.  Also, what if the changes were applied a few rows at a time?  Or is there a data integrity issue that requires you do atomically make all the changes, then flip to the new table?